# Underpowered studies and minimum effect size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, effect-size, statistical-power

We know that that underpowered studies lead to overestimated effect sizes (conditioned on statistical significance). See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176384/do-underpowered-studies-have-increased-likelihood-of-false-positives), [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrn3475), and [here](http://andrewgelman.com/2014/11/17/power-06-looks-like-get-used/) for discussions on this topic. Now, let's suppose that the true effect size $e$ is much smaller than the minimum effect size $E$ that we use in the power calculations. As I understand it, this is not necessarily bad, if we're only interested in detecting effect of size $E$ or larger. What this means is that my study is powered appropriately to detect $E$, but underpowered to detect $e$. So my question is: is the effect estimate from this study likely to be overestimated (because we're underpowered w.r.t $e$), or is it fine (because we're well powered w.r.t $E$, which is the effect size we care about)? If the answer is the former, then why it is acceptable to specify a minimum effect size? Wouldn't we always want to specify (our best estimate of) the true effect size?